# How to add datafile in SYSTEM tablespece in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration

i am trying to this way to add datafile in system tablespace but it gives error please suggest. how to add datafile in it.

```
SQL> ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM ADD DATAFILE '/u01/oracle/oradata 
     /orcl/system02.dbf' SIZE 10240M;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-19502: write error on file "/u01/oracle/oradata/orcl/system02.dbf",  
blockno
193536 (blocksize=8192)
ORA-27072: File I/O error
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 4
Additional information: 193536
Additional information: 610304
```

Comment: Does directory `/u01/oracle/oradata/orcl` exist? What is the path for your existing data file (from dba_data_files)?

Comment: thank you@ Alex Poole  Yes path is existing like '/u01/oracle/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf'

Comment: I guess it looks like an underlying filesystem error, from the blockno reference. Does your filesystem have 10G free?

Answer (score 1):

You might not be having sufficient space on the drive, instead of allocating 10g chunk, allocate 100m and allow to autoextend on 10g;

```
 ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM ADD DATAFILE '/u01/oracle/oradata/orcl/system02.dbf' SIZE 100m autoextend on maxsize 10g;
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the how much space available system tablespace using below commands:

```
select sum(bytes) from dba_free_space where tablespace_name='SYSTEM';
```

and

```
select tablespace_name, extent_management from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name='SYSTEM';
```

then try this..

```
alter tablespace SYSTEM add datafile '/u01/oracle/oradata/orcl/system02.dbf' SIZE 10240M;
```